# Can a component be styled based on its closest parent in pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

If I use this css, the `span`'s text color is determined by its closest parent (i.e. text is blue):

```css
.red {
    color: red;
}

.blue {
    color: blue;
}

.green {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
    <div class="red">
        <div class="blue">
            <div class="my-component">
                <span>Hello World</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I want this behavior for `.my-component` specifically. I therefore added `.my-component` to my selector but suddenly, the `span`'s text color is determined by the definition order (i.e. text is green):

```css
.red .my-component {
    color: red;
}

.blue .my-component {
    color: blue;
}

.green .my-component {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
    <div class="red">
        <div class="blue">
            <div class="my-component">
                <span>Hello World</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is this?

**EDIT**

Ok, so I messed up a bit here. As noted in the comments, I was mostly surprised that the distance between `.red` and `.my-component` did not affect specificity. However, my second question was the one I was really interested in. This question has already received a lot of great answers to the first question, so I'm reverting this question to its original state and will split the second question off into a new one. Thank you all for the great answers!

Comment: The why is because the css rules you've made all have the same [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: I guess they all end up pointing at the same div in the end of case 2 whereas they point to different divs in case 1. I was just a bit surprised that the distance between parent and child did not make a difference in the specificity.

Comment: Question 2 was split off into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73422180/can-you-make-the-distance-between-selectors-matter-for-specificity-in-css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the question was (originally) titled: "Can a component be styled based on its *closest* parent in pure CSS?" and looking at the original examples given
you can do it like this:

```css
.red > .my-component {
    color: red;
}

.blue > .my-component {
    color: blue;
}

.green > .my-component {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
    <div class="red">
        <div class="blue">
            <div class="my-component">
                <span>Hello World</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `>` demands a *direct* parent-child relationship. A "grandparent" will have no effect on the target element's formatting.

However, the above snippet will *not* work if the target div is placed *several levels under* the innermost "colored" div.

Comment: That's true. I would like this to work at an unknown depth though... I'll update the question.

Comment: I reverted my update since so many people answered the first part of the question immediately.  I split the second part + unkown depth off to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73422180/can-you-make-the-distance-between-selectors-matter-for-specificity-in-css

Answer (score 1):

This is all determined by [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> **Specificity** is the algorithm used by browsers to determine the [CSS declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/What_is_CSS#css_syntax) that is the most relevant to an element, which in turn, determines the property value to apply to the element. The specificity algorithm calculates the weight of a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference#selectors) to determine which rule from competing CSS declarations gets applied to an element.

With this being said, you can use more specific selectors such as the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) `>` with reference to the element to specify styles. You'll notice the more specific I get with the selectors that it will take precedence over other styles.

```css
.red .my-component {
  color: red;
}

.blue > .my-component span {
  color: blue;
}

.green .my-component {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
  <div class="red">
    <div class="blue">
      <div class="my-component">
        <span>Hello World</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I were to use `.green > .red > .blue > .my-component span` in the last part of the CSS then this would take precedence because it is more specific. An example of that is below.

```css
.red .my-component {
  color: red;
}

.blue > .my-component span {
  color: blue;
}

.green > .red > .blue > .my-component span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
  <div class="red">
    <div class="blue">
      <div class="my-component">
        <span>Hello World</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this happens because the code below:

```
.red {color: red;}
.blue {color: blue;}
.green {color: green;}
```

influences the color of the element and its children.
Since one children is inside the another and CSS selectors here have the same priority then the one that is the cloest (the last) has the final word.
The color value is inherited but every time changed because of your classes. That's why the sequence in html has a meaning.

```
.red .my-component {color: red;}
.blue .my-component {color: blue;}
.green .my-component {color: green;}
```

In the second case you are targeting only .my-components inside the proper class elements so when you change color to red, you are then changing it to blue and at last to green. That's why the sequence in css file has a meaning and not in html.

I hope this will help.