# Can you make the distance between selectors matter for specificity in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Originally split off from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73421755/can-a-component-be-styled-based-on-its-closest-parent-in-pure-css) question.

If I use this css, the `span`'s text color is determined by its closest parent (i.e. text is blue):

```css
.blue {
    color: blue;
}

.green {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
    <!-- more divs with color classes -->
        <div class="blue">
            <div>
                <!-- Unknown depth without color classes -->
                    <div>
                        <div class="my-component">
                            <span>Hello World</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- -->
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- -->
</div>
```

However, I want this behavior for `.my-component` specifically. I therefore added `.my-component` to my selector but suddenly, the `span`'s text color is determined by the definition order (i.e. text is green):

```css
.blue .my-component {
    color: blue;
}

.green .my-component {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
    <!-- more divs with color classes -->
        <div class="blue">
            <div>
                <!-- Unknown depth without color classes -->
                    <div>
                        <div class="my-component">
                            <span>Hello World</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- -->
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- -->
</div>
```

I understand *why* this is (specificity; see [Can a component be styled based on its closest parent in pure CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73421755/can-a-component-be-styled-based-on-its-closest-parent-in-pure-css)) but would like to know *how to work around it*.

Is there a way to get the second example to behave as the first (only using CSS/HTML)?

Comment: I realize this is a simplified case to illustrate the question, but it suggests there's a bigger problem. You have two classes of equal specificity and (more importantly) equal "significance" (utilities) that are built for inheritance, not directly applying styles. If each were setting `background`, then there's no issue. Or if the utility class was directly on the thing you're styling (the component div) there wouldn't be an issue. The real case is likely much more complex, but might still have room to improve code organization. ... @temani-afif's answer also works.

Comment: The real case is an implementation of the material design 3 outlined text field: https://m3.material.io/components/text-fields/specs#68b00bd6-ab40-4b4f-93d9-ed1fbbc5d06e . The problem is that the label needs to make a part of the border of the text field "transparent" which could be different colors in different contexts. My first solution was to add a utility class `textfield-outlined-bg-${background}` but it would be better if the text field would simply "know" what the current background is.

Comment: Since I'm using tailwindcss I can be fairly sure a changed background means a `bg-${background}` utility class will be available with an ancestor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS variables. The closest class will override all the previous ones and win the game.

```css
.blue {
    --c: blue;
}
.green  {
    --c: green;
}

.my-component {
  color: var(--c);
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
    <!-- more divs with color classes -->
        <div class="blue">
            <div>
                <!-- Unknown depth without color classes -->
                    <div>
                        <div class="my-component">
                            <span>Hello World</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- -->
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- -->
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain why this works?

Comment: @WillD this works due to specificity. Check out the original question [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73421755/can-a-component-be-styled-based-on-its-closest-parent-in-pure-css) for a more detailed explanation

Comment: @FelixZY no, there is no specificity in play here. It's all about the *cascade* and inheritance.

Comment: @WillD This works because CSS custom properties belong to their context in the DOM. Similar to the original question about "distance", `.my-component` is blue because the `.blue` context is a more direct ancestor. It doesn't matter the order that the contexts are defined in the stylesheet.

Comment: The more I think about it, this is the correct solution, at least for my case. Thank you, and thank you for helping me get my vocabulary right 

Answer (score -1):

Fight specificity with specificity.

UPDATE: use the default :root selector as a starting point, to override other rules.

```css
:root .blue .my-component {
    color: blue;
}

.green .my-component {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
    <!-- more divs with color classes -->
        <div class="blue">
            <div>
                <!-- Unknown depth without color classes -->
                    <div>
                        <div class="my-component">
                            <span>Hello World</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- -->
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- -->
</div>
```

Comment: This is a slippery slope, constantly creating escalating specificity for new cases.

Comment: Since the number of color classes is unknown, the number of selectors would quickly explode out of control. I understand the suggestion but do not consider this a practical solution.